# Deny access from specific word in referrer in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, referrer-spam

this is my first post, and I'm not so good in English (I speak baguette), sorry and thanks in advance.
**Background**: My website has huge access considered as spam, from Indonesia. I tried to check what was their common points (ip adress, browsers etc), and I found that their referrer is from a google result page on porn keyword (mainly "xnxx"). So I want to deny access with "xnxx" mention on it referrer. Posts I found about denying a whole site, but it would be nonsense to deny the whole google for me.
**Solution I tried**: I receive this code to put on my htaccess, but it didn't work.

```
#deny indonesia spam by its refering sites
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \bxnxx\b [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Do you have any idea about how I could fix it?